# c++ Spawn a specified amount of thread to all run the same function until one thread reaches the result

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function

```
string theGoodString(string someString) {
     string goodString;
     bool criteriaMet = false;
     while (!criteriaMet) {
           goodString = processString(someString);
          // some criteria
           criteriaMet = true;
     }
     return goodString;
}
```

How to make new function/s where I spawn a specified amount of thread and have it **only** output back **the first successful result**.

```
void runTheGoodString(int numThread, const string& someString){
    cout << "Thread " << numThread << " starting" << endl;
    string goodString = theGoodString(someString);
    cout << "Thread " << numThread << " finished with result: " << goodString << endl;
}

void runTheGoodStringParallel(const string& someString, int numThreads) {
    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back(runTheGoodString, i, someString);
    }
    for (thread& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Currently this output back to me all the thread results.

Comment: Also you don't want to spawn more threads then you have cores, see : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency. Side note stop using `using namespace std'`. Make `criteriaMet` static and atomic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag):

```
#include <atomic>
std::atomic_flag complete;

void runTheGoodString(int numThread, const string& someString){
    cout << "Thread " << numThread << " starting" << endl;
    string goodString = theGoodString(someString);
    if (!complete.test_and_set()) {
        cout << "Thread " << numThread << " finished with result: " << goodString << endl;
    } else {
        // do nothing, some other thread won
    }
}

void runTheGoodStringParallel(const string& someString, int numThreads) {
    complete.clear();
    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
        threads.emplace_back(runTheGoodString, i, someString);
    }
    for (thread& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

You may also want to do something like `if (complete.test()) return;` periodically inside your computation loop, so that the other threads don't keep computing after the answer has been found.

(In this case it actually suffices to use `std::memory_order_relaxed` on all operations on `complete`.)

Comment: Yes it should be std::memory_order_relaxed.